# How to use mapply with lists

Tags: r, list, mapply

I will like to use mapply in this way:

```
result<-mapply(sum,c(1,2,3),c(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6)))
```

and get the following:

```
result
[[1]]
2 3
[[2]]
5 6
[[3]]
8 9
```

But instead I got:

```
Result
2 4 6 5 7 9
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of `c(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6))`

```
c(list(1,2),list(3,4),list(5,6))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 4

#[[5]]
#[1] 5

#[[6]]
#[1] 6
```

It's a list of length 6. This is probably not what you want. The structure that you want is :

```
list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 5 6
```

Also `sum` returns 1 number, to get expected output you should use `+` instead.

```
Map(`+`,c(1,2,3),list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6)))

#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6

#[[3]]
#[1] 8 9
```

With `mapply` you have to use `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to maintain the list structure.

```
mapply(`+`,c(1,2,3),list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```